# After converting from Int to Hex value and then Append hex value to the Data object getting error Swift?

Tags: swift, hex, decimal, nsdata

I have code as below after converting to hex value trying to appending data object but it gives me the below error:

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
let n = 585
let result = 255 - n % 256 //182 is result
let hexValue = String(result, radix: 16) //b6 is result
var returnMsg = "[1,1,1, ,#00300".data(using: .utf8) as! Data
returnMsg.append(UInt8(hexValue)!)
```

Here I am trying to add b6 to data object.

Comment: A few thoughts: `let intValue = UInt8("b6")` That's returning `nil`. It seems logical. That's why it crashes, because then `UInt8(hexValue)` is nil, and you force the unwrap on it using `!`. Why do you use the `String`? What about just doing `returnMsg.append(result)`? But now, there is an issue because you can't append like that a Int (UInt8) to a `Data` object like that.

Comment: I couldn't duplicate the issue. After adding the first four lines of your code into a new project's `viewDidLoad` and adding a simple `print(returnMsg)` yielded "15 bytes" but compile errors on `append`. BUT... I'm now seeing an opening quote (for string?) possible misplaced and an opening bracket inside it (for an array?) without a closing one. Any chance you misposted your code? To summarize, `"[1,1,1, ,#00300".data(using: .utf8)"` is syntactically compiling but makes no sense without (at least a closing bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of a string to get `result` as a hex string is of no use just to append to `returnMsg`. Simply append the `result`.

```
let n = 585
let result = 255 - n % 256 //182 is result
var returnMsg = "[1,1,1, ,#00300".data(using: .utf8)!
returnMsg.append(UInt8(result))
```

Your crash is resulting from force-unwrapping `UInt8(hexValue)`. Passing in the string `b6` gives a `nil` result and the force-unwrap of `nil` always results in a crash and the error message you are seeing. The `UInt8` initializer that takes a string only accepts a base-10 integer. You can see this in the documentation:

> The string passed as `description` may begin with a plus or minus sign character (+ or -), followed by one or more numeric digits (0-9).
>
> If `description` is in an invalid format, or if the value it denotes in base 10 is not representable, the result is `nil`.

Comment: I understand that and thanks for the tip.. but here 182 is decimal value and you are appending decimal value directly but I need to append hex value instead  of that...

Comment: Perhaps you are asking the wrong question. Do you wish to append the byte value of 182 (b6) or do you wish to append the UTF8 encoded bytes of the string `b6`? There's a huge difference between those two choices. This answer assumes you wish to add the one byte 182 (b6).

Comment: thanks for clarification ..I am trying to add  byte value of 182 in hex format to the data  ..

Comment: Then my answer is what you want. A byte is a byte. The format is only relevant when displaying it to the user. There is no need to convert anything to hex to append the byte.

Comment: thanks..we are sending that data to IoT device and the device expecting in hex format .. will ask them clearly and if hey want in hex format I need ti find another way ..!

Comment: The format they need has nothing to do with how you create the `Data` on your Swift code. They will get the proper bytes as long as you send the proper bytes and based on what you have stated, these are the proper bytes.